# How to translate and modify map.resources :document

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resources, routes

```
map.resources :document
```

After adding this route, I now have an automatic "`edit_document_path`". I wanted to change this to "`annotate_document_path`"? Will it automatically pick this up if I add a new view and controller method? How does it translate from the resource route to these "path" notations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jarrod is correct. `map.resources` by default only adds the RESTful routes. To get the route you want, the line should read

```
map.resources :document, :member => {:annotate => :get}
```

:member means this route will have an associated document_id, :annotate will be part of the url, and :get is the HTTP method used to access this routes.

With this line, you should have access to the `annotate_document_path(document_id)` helper method.

Answer (score 1):

map.resources adds RESTful routes. You're looking for a named route. [More info at RailsGuides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#named-routes).